# Addclass to Menu Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class dynamicly to the menu I have on my website, which is build up as followed.

```
<nav>
    <ul id="" class="mini-menu">
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="over-jellyfish">Over Jellyfish</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="hoofd-menu">
        <li class="websites"><a id="dekstop_menu" href="websites"><i class="fa fa-desktop text-center"></i>Websites</a></li>
        <li class="support"><a id="support_menu" href="support"><i class="fa fa-comment-o text-center"></i>Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

with Jquery I am tryint to add the class active to the mini-menu by doing the following steps.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var str = window.location.pathname;
    var page = str.split("/");
    p=page[2];
    var active = p=page[2];
    console.log(active);  

    jQuery('.mini-menu a').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('href')  ===  active) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Yet i seem to miss something here, cause nothing shows up within the html as adding a class to the link. Am I missing the fact that the link is not a direct child of the class mini-nav? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle and explain your issue?

Comment: excuse me, typo .. it's mini-menu .. fixed it

Comment: Does the console.log() return the correct string?

Comment: No maybe it's phrased wrong, i am trying to check if the variable active equals to the href link within the anchor tag. if that is true, addclass "active"

Comment: Works fine here ? http://jsfiddle.net/w10xoa8t/1/

Comment: @Anton yes, it returns the variable from what i need back. So in case i am on the blog page, it returns the word blog back (since its the page I am on, and so on.)

Comment: It should work fine, btw you don't need to use .each() to find the link element with the correct href. You can use attribute selector `jQuery('.mini-menu a[href="'+active+'"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
jQuery(function() {
    var str = window.location.pathname;
    var page = str.split("/");
    p=page[2];
    var active = p=page[2];
    console.log(active);  

    jQuery('.mini-menu a').each(function() {
        (function (self) {
        if (jQuery(self).attr('href')  ===  active) {
            jQuery(self).addClass('active');
        }
        })(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for. I adds the class now :) I ll accept when I can.

Comment: It's because of "each". When you are using "each" and that you would like to change something : create a function like I did to copy the current variables inside. If you don't do that, the "this" will always be equal to the last element when you will try to change something.